# Apache use SFTP instead of HTTP to serve files

Tags: apache-http-server, ftp, file-transfer, http, sftp

Is it possible to serve files using SFTP instead of HTTP for Apache? I'm trying to host files on Apache and the files are 100MB+.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Apache is an HTTP server, not an SSH/SFTP server.

HTTP is perfectly suitable for distributing files as large as multiple gigabytes. 100 MB isn't even especially big; Apache should handle that just fine.

Comment: I found this: httpd.apache.org/mod_ftp . Am I mistaken that it overrides HTTP file transfer and servers files using FTP instead?

Comment: @tyleax mod_ftp is for FTP. It has nothing to do with SFTP, what is a completely different protocol.

Comment: @tyleax That module is not strictly speaking a part of Apache HTTPD. It's distributed separately, and the most recent release was just over 10 years ago. It's unlikely to be a viable option.